# Fate of Captain Wu of HMS Cometary

Tags: honorverse

At the start of *A Rising Thunder*, a Captain Wu of HMS Cometary has quite a lengthy introductory scene.

During his time on stage Captain Wu introduces the escalating nature of the conflict between Manticore and the Solarian League, describes the mandatory recall notice issued to all shipping and allows the merchant skipper of the Vortrekker that he's currently talking with to ignore the recall, make their next delivery to Klondike and then return to Manticore.

As far as I know, Captain Wu is never heard from again neither is the Vortrekker. Does their story get any resolution? Captain Wu specifically says he's acting outside his orders to allow the Vortrekker to make its scheduled delivery and the state of relations between the two powers escalates quickly afterwards.

Did the Vortrekker make its delivery and return to Manticore? Was Captain Wu reprimanded or commended over the incident? Which book or books did they get any follow up in?

Comment: http://www.forums.davidweber.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=8990&start=50 is not exactly an answer but gives more info